# Load lng and lat coordinates into MapQuest from XML file

Tags: javascript, php, xml, mapquest

What I'm trying to do is load coordinates on my MapQuest map from a PHP/XML file.
Here is the whole scenario:
My page loads and show the map, then I want to click a button that calls a function. In this function I uses AJAX to fetch coordinates from an external file called coor.xml. In coor.xml I use PHP to grab Coordinates (Lat and Lng) out of my database and generate a XML file. Then those coordinates gets displayed on my map without reloading the page.
The problem I have is it doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
MQA.withModule('shapes', function() {
    
       var line = new MQA.LineOverlay();
        
        var lineCoordinates = "";
        var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("coordinates");
        for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
            var lng = x[i].getElementsByTagName("lng")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            var lat = x[i].getElementsByTagName("lat")[0].firstChild.nodeValue
            if((x.length - 1) == i)
            {
                lineCoordinates = lineCoordinates + lng + ', ' + lat;
            }
            else
            {
                lineCoordinates = lineCoordinates + lng + ', ' + lat + ', ';
            }
        }
       line.setShapePoints([lineCoordinates]);
     
       map.addShape(line);
```

This is what it should display:

```
line.setShapePoints([-27.955591, 25.111084, -27.974998, 26.759033, -29.113775, 26.253662]);
```

But I get the following error:

> -Unexpected value NaN,NaN parsing points attribute.
>
> -Aq is undefined

Here is my coor.xml file example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<markers>
    <coordinates>
        <id>1</id>
        <lat>-27.955591</lng>
        <lng>25.111084</lat>
        <text>Position 1</text>
    </coordinates>
    <coordinates>
        <id>2</id>
        <lat>-27.974998</lng>
        <lng>26.759033</lat>
        <text>Position 2</text>
    </coordinates>
    <coordinates>
        <id>3</id>
        <lat>-29.113775</lng>
        <lng>26.253662</lat>
        <text>Position 3</text>
    </coordinates>
</markers>
```

Hope I explained this correctly :-)

Answer (score 0):

Those shape points work great for me.  Is there a url where we can see this happening?

Comment: Hi MQBrain. I will send you a link in the morning as its a bit late for me know. 23H48 at night to be exact :-)